# Getting $USER inside shell script when running with sudo?

Tags: unix, shell, environment-variables, sudo

How do I get the correct $USER if I run a shell script with sudo ?

I run them as postinstall scripts in a Mac install package, where they are being sudo-ed automatically, but I need to do stuff with the username.

$HOME is correct, though. The inelegant method would be to extract the name from the home path, but I wonder if there is a natural way to do this.

I can't influence the way the scripts are being called, as it's an automatic call inside the installer.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

On my system the variable `$SUDO_USER` is set to the caller's user name.

You shouldn't extract the username from the `${HOME}` variable directly. It's being configured and not calculated. To Extract the username you could take a look into `/etc/passwd` file, but this is very system dependent, e.g. sometimes you have to look into a LDAP directory or the entries are propagated through NIS ...

Comment: For those landing here because gnome-terminal dropped support for `logname`, this seems to work well `$(logname 2>/dev/null || echo $SUDO_USER)`.  Tested on MacOS too.  Bug report: https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=747046

Comment: logname 2>/dev/null || echo $SUDO_USER , command worked for me in the OS Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS and Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

Answer (score 29):

You can use `$(logname)`, which returns your login name even if you are currently sudoing.

Comment: @Knetic for future you and other Googlers, it may not: https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=747046

Comment: It is returning sudo name on Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS

Comment: On Arch Linux I suggest using `echo $LOGNAME`... But it depends on your environment variables

Answer (score 19):

Inspect the variable **SUDO_USER**.

http://www.gratisoft.us/sudo/man/sudo.html#environment

Another way to get the user is via the **who** command.  This is useful sometimes when you don't care if the user has sudo'd or not.

```
who -m | awk '{print $1;}'
```

Answer (score 9):

`SUDO_USER` isn't portable. It's unset on Fedora 17.

The `$USER` and `$UID` variables aren't predictable when invoking sudo either. Some distros report the sudoer, others report the root user.

It's by no means perfect, but you could use `test -w ~root && echo I have write access to ~root`.