# Get username of current session

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux

I am writing a program in python, which is run as root (with sudo) and I am trying to get the username of the session it was run in.
I tried with `os.getuid()` combined with the `pwd` module but it returns `root`.
I thought of getting the uid of the grandfather process (program -> sudo -> program with the right uid), but I think this is not an elegant solution, and it doesn't work in all cases.
How to get the username (or uid) of the current session ?

PS: I am not English so there may be some mistakes in my message

Comment: Depends on how you get root. Best chance might be the `SUDO_*` environmental variables.

Comment: this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1629605/getting-user-inside-shell-script-when-running-with-sudo

Comment: try:  'loginctl list-sessions'

Comment: ok `logname` seems to be the best solution, I will use that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to do this on UNIX OS's is by using the "SUDO_USER" environment variable:

```
>>> import os
>>> os.getenv("SUDO_USER")
'test_user'
```

The only caveat is that this is not truly portable, for example on Fedora 17 this variable is not set (But will work for almost all environments and distros).

---

There is an alternative much more bulky solution that covers much more edge cases, [this might work better for your use case.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/626389)

```
import os
import shutil
import getpass
import pwd

def get_user():
    """Try to find the user who called sudo/pkexec."""
    try:
        return os.getlogin()
    except OSError:
        # failed in some ubuntu installations and in systemd services
        pass

    try:
        user = os.environ['USER']
    except KeyError:
        # possibly a systemd service. no sudo was used
        return getpass.getuser()

    if user == 'root':
        try:
            return os.environ['SUDO_USER']
        except KeyError:
            # no sudo was used
            pass

        try:
            pkexec_uid = int(os.environ['PKEXEC_UID'])
            return pwd.getpwuid(pkexec_uid).pw_name
        except KeyError:
            # no pkexec was used
            pass

    return user
```

EG of working cases:

```
$ python3 getuser.py
test_user
$ sudo python3 getuser.py
test_user
$ pkexec python3 getuser.py
test_user
```